# Type checking python function signatures of Protocol subclass with mypy

Tags: python, types, mypy

Is there a way to safely type-check a python class which subclasses a protocol?

If I define a protocol with a certain method function signature, then implicit subclasses must define a method with a compatible signature:

```
# protocols.py

from abc import abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol

class SupportsPublish(Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def publish(self, topic: str):
        ...

def publish(m: SupportsPublish):
    m.publish("topic")

@dataclass
class Publishable:
    foo: str = "bar"

    def publish(self):
        print(self)

publish(Publishable())

# ✗ mypy protocols.py       
# protocols.py:24: error: Argument 1 to "publish" has incompatible type "Publishable"; expected "SupportsPublish"  [arg-type]
# protocols.py:24: note: Following member(s) of "Publishable" have conflicts:
# protocols.py:24: note:     Expected:
# protocols.py:24: note:         def publish(self, topic: str) -> Any
# protocols.py:24: note:     Got:
# protocols.py:24: note:         def publish(self) -> Any
# Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

But, if I explicitly subtype `SupportsPublish`, mypy does not report a type error:

```
...
@dataclass
class Publishable(SupportsPublish):
...

# ✗ mypy protocols.py
# Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Based on [this blurb](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#explicitly-declaring-implementation) from the PEP, I expected the type checker to find the function signature mismatch:

> Note that there is little difference between explicit and implicit subtypes, the main benefit of explicit subclassing is to get some protocol methods “for free”. In addition, type checkers can statically verify that the class actually implements the protocol correctly:

This is my environment:

```
> mypy --version
mypy 1.3.0 (compiled: yes)
> python --version
Python 3.9.17
```

I expected mypy to point out the function signature mismatch.

Comment: When you subclass a protocol you're defining a new protocol, and it overrides the requirements of the base protocol.

Comment: The mypy documentation suggests you have to include `Protocol` as an explicit subclass to define a new profile:

> Note that inheriting from an existing protocol does not automatically turn the subclass into a protocol – it just creates a regular (non-protocol) class or ABC that implements the given protocol (or protocols). The Protocol base class must always be explicitly present if you are defining a protocol


Link: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#defining-subprotocols-and-subclassing-protocols

Comment: You're not fully annotating your functions. Specifically, `Publishable.publish` doesn't have any type annotations, so it's treated as untyped. Get into the habit of writing `-> None` as a return annotation if a function doesn't return anything. Working warnings: [mypy-playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=f80d4e81f014ec627b350510504b3325)

Comment: You know, I tried running `mypy` in strict mode, and fixed the missing type annotations. I thought I ran into the same type error, but retrying it I can reproduce the "error: Signature ..." error. Thanks!


(My editor (VSCode) is still not displaying this warning, but that's no longer a mypy problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to point out, as was established in the comments, it is not in fact true that if you explicitly subtype `SupportsPublish`, mypy does not report a type error.

The problem is that you weren't type annotating your method, which essentially tells mypy "don't check this".

If you do, for example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol

class SupportsPublish(Protocol):
    def publish(self, topic: str) -> None:
        ...

def publish(m: SupportsPublish):
    m.publish("topic")

@dataclass
class Publishable:
    foo: str = "bar"

    def publish(self) -> None:
        print(self)
```

Then mypy *will* complain:

```bash
(py311) Juans-MBP:~ juan$ mypy foo.py
foo.py:18: error: Argument 1 to "publish" has incompatible type "Publishable"; expected "SupportsPublish"  [arg-type]
foo.py:18: note: Following member(s) of "Publishable" have conflicts:
foo.py:18: note:     Expected:
foo.py:18: note:         def publish(self, topic: str) -> None
foo.py:18: note:     Got:
foo.py:18: note:         def publish(self) -> None
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Because this is a *requirement of just regular subclassing with method overriding*.

If you aren't going to run mypy with full `--strict` mode, at least somehow (through how it is invoked or by using a `mypy.ini`) make sure you have `--disallow-untyped-defs` or `--disallow-untyped-calls`

Comment: 'The problem is that you weren't type annotating your method, which essentially tells mypy "don't check this".' <-- yes, this is indeed the problem! I am curious if there is a checker mode that allows type inference (when the return type is not annotated) but still checks method overrides.

Comment: @AndrewStewart not that I'm aware. If the return type by itself is left blank then it is inferred to be `typing.Any`

Comment: So I played around with this a little more. You're right that it has nothing to do with protocols. However, it sometimes correctly checks types even without annotated return types, and sometimes it does *not*: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=c5f248086ee04ad9e6920f6f34e874c2 Do you understand why?

Answer (score 0):

The `publish` method *must have the same signature in the class as in the protocol* to conform to the protocol. Also, you shouldn't subclass protocols except possibly to create other protocols; they are implicit in the sense that a class (or other thing) "conforms to" the protocol if it [matches a superset of the protocol definition](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#subtyping-relationships-with-other-types), not by explicitly linking to it:

> A concrete type `X` is a subtype of protocol `P` if and only if `X` implements all protocol members of `P` with compatible types.

In other words, for a class to be a subtype of `SupportsPublish` it is necessary and sufficient for it to have a method with signature `publish(self, topic: str) -> None`.

[Here's a version which supports `mypy --strict`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=f28d29f9b13f793a07031a30fc91081a&flags=strict):

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol

class SupportsPublish(Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def publish(self, topic: str) -> None:
        ...

def publish(m: SupportsPublish) -> None:
    m.publish("topic")

@dataclass
class Publishable:
    foo: str = "bar"

    def publish(self, topic: str) -> None:
        print(topic)

publish(Publishable())
```

Comment: "Also, you shouldn't subclass protocols except possibly to create other protocols; they are implicit in the sense that a class (or other thing) "conforms to" the protocol if it matches a superset of the protocol definition, not by explicitly linking to it"   <--- 


I'm not sure I understand this. The PEP explicitly marks this out as a use case: https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#explicitly-declaring-implementation

Comment: You're right, I'd never seen that. "Note that there is little difference between explicit and implicit subtypes, the main benefit of explicit subclassing is to get some protocol methods “for free”. In addition, type checkers can statically verify that the class actually implements the protocol correctly:" Huh. Not sure when that's useful.